# Deserializing a list of JSON String in an Apex Method

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am passing a JSON string to my Apex Method.  When I try to deserialize it, I get the error:  Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void deserialize(List, System.Type) from the type System.JSON

I am being prevented from saving my Apex Class.  Here is my code for that piece:

```java
public static void  createCaseImages(List<String> imgs, String caseId){
    System.debug(imgs);
    List<imageSelectionWrapper> wrpList = 
        (List<imageSelectionWrapper>) JSON.deserialize(imgs, List<imageSelectionWrapper>.class);
}
```

It won't let me save this piece.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You can't deploy it, because [`JSON.deserialize()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) method has different signature and takes a variable of
`String` type as a first param, not `List<String>`.